# How to generate a deeply nested JSON from CSV?

Tags: python, json, dataframe, csv, dictionary

I am trying to generate a kind of CMS in the front-end that expects the data comes from the backend as a JSON in the following manner -

```
[
 {
      "type": "SECTION",
      "subtitle": null,
      "title": "Overview",
      "content": [
        {
          "type": "P",
          "text":
            "This is the first paragraph.",
          "config": {},
        },
        {
          "type": "P",
          "text":
            "This is the second paragraph.",
          "config": {"extra-info": "this is extra information"},
        },  
        {
          "type": "SUBSECTION",
          "title": "This has 3 parts:",
          "content": [
            { "subtitle": "part 1", "title": "Hi how are you?" },
            {
              "subtitle": "part 2",
              "title": "I am good",
            },
            {
              "subtitle": "part 3",
              "title":
                "Does this work?",
            },
          ],
          "config": {},
        },
      ],
    },
 {
      "type": "SECTION",
      "subtitle": null,
      "title": "section 2",
      "content": [
        {
          "type": "P",
          "text":
            "This is the first paragraph.",
          "config": {},
        },
         
         
      ],
    },
]
```

This format is important to create a modular CMS where I am rendering a different component based on the type of content.

The problem is that it is being read from a CSV which has this particular format -

| REFERENCE | TEXT | other data |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Section#L1->Header#1->Statement#1 | This is section 1 | extra info |
| Section#L1->Paragraph#1->Statement#1 | hi from paragraph 1 |  |
| Section#L1->Paragraph#1->Numbered_list#1->Statement#1 | this is nested paragraph 1 |  |
| Section#L1->Paragraph#1->Numbered_list#2->Statement#1 | This is nested paragraph 2 |  |
| Section#L1->Paragraph#1->Numbered_list#3->Statement#1 | this is nested paragraph 3 |  |

Out of this, the text field cannot be modified but the reference field can be modified so that I can parse it to make the desired JSON. Is it possible to have the REFERENCE column in such a way that I can parse and effectively convert this CSV to the expected deeply nested JSON?

This needs to be done in Python. I am trying to use a few CSV to JSON libraries but they don't support the level of nesting I am looking for.

I have tried using dpath.util to parse the REFERENCE Column and add it to a JSON.

```py
def create_json_from_df(df):
    final_json = {}

    for ind in df.index:
        path = df["REFERENCE"][ind].replace("#", "-").replace("->", "/")
        dpath.util.new(final_json, path, {"text": df["text"][ind], "otherdata": df["other data"][ind] })

    return final_json
```

Problem is that this will generate JSON with unique keys. I am trying to get an array and multi-level nesting.

Comment: is that valid json? ;)

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: also, you'll need some custom logic to create the nested dictionary, then output to json, is the `type` key the same as the reference part?

Comment: @TenaciousB, Hi. I have edited the JSON. Hope it is valid now.

Comment: @KlausD. Sorry if this was not the correct format. I have tried using dpath.util to parse and then push new keys to array but it needs key for every input. But Sometime they are arrays and the objects need to be pushed only. This is only what I could come up with as I am not much familar with Python.

Comment: @TenaciousB No but the type (or any other information about an element) can be obtained from any other custom column.

Comment: It is expected that you present some code you already have.

Comment: I have edited the question with a short answer. I have omitted the whole code as to how I got the dataframe though as it is not related to the question.